# factory method is not flexible enough regarding constructors with different parameters or am I missing something?

Tags: java, factory

Please consider these 2 classes:

```
public class Audi implements Car {
private String color;
private int turnAssistLevel;

public Audi() {
}

public Audi(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public Audi(String color, int turnAssistLevel) {
    this.color = color;
    this.turnAssistLevel = turnAssistLevel;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public int getTurnAssistLevel() {
    return turnAssistLevel;
}

public void setTurnAssistLevel(int turnAssistLevel) {
    this.turnAssistLevel = turnAssistLevel;
}
}

public class Bmw implements Car {
private String color;
private boolean hasXDrive;

public Bmw() {
}

public Bmw(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public Bmw(String color, boolean hasXDrive) {
    this.color = color;
    this.hasXDrive = hasXDrive;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public boolean isHasXDrive() {
    return hasXDrive;
}

public void setHasXDrive(boolean hasXDrive) {
    this.hasXDrive = hasXDrive;
}
}
```

I would like to write some factory using factory methods:

Let's say I want to have some factory methods to return empty cars. Easy to do:

```
public interface CarFactory {
public Car makeCar();
}
```

As an implementation:

```
public class BmwCarFactory implements CarFactory {

public Car makeCar() {
    return new Bmw();
}
}
```

The same I could do for Audi.

Now, say I need a car with color. As I see it I need to define a factory that knows how to do cars with colors:

```
public interface CarWithColorFactory {
Car makeCar(String color);
}
```

Now to make a Bmw with color:

```
public class BmwWithColorCarFactory implements CarWithColorFactory {
public Car makeCar(String color) {
    return new Bmw(color);
}
}
```

The same for Audi.

But now, say I need to do a Bmw with both color and xDrive. Or an Audi with both color and turnAssistLevel. How would I do this using factory method???

Using simple factory I'd probably do:

```
public class SimpleCarFactory {

public Car makeBmw(String color, boolean hasXDrive) {
    return new Bmw(color, hasXDrive);
}

public Car makeAudi(String color, int turnAssistLevel) {
    return new Audi(color, turnAssistLevel);
}
}
```

So how to do it using factory method?

Kind regards,

Comment: Is this question much different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637621/are-all-of-these-method-signatures-valid-for-simple-factory-pattern ? You have not given any feedback on that question yet.

Comment: I did, please check again

Comment: And yes it's different than this, that one is about simple factory not factory method, check again close please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Factory Method provides configuration through subclassing. I find it simpler, therefore, to make *all* configuration decisions in subclasses. In practice, this means Factory Methods will be nullary (taking no arguments).***

The Factory Method returns an abstract product, with no consideration given to that product's concrete properties. This behavior is consistent with the design principle of *programming to an interface*. For example, a program needing to drive a `Car` should depend on the `Car` interface. It should not depend on a black BMW with XDrive. It is strictly the responsibility of the `BMW` subclass (and possibly the `BMW_XDrive` subclass) to configure such a concrete product.

To reiterate: the consumer of the Factory Method (aka the Creator) **does not configure the product**. Here is an example where the consumer (`FactoryMethod`) needs to drive a `Car` and specifies the method `rentCar()` in order for subclasses to provide that dependency. The two subclasses each configure a specific concrete product, but the consumer simply gets a `Car`.

```
public abstract class FactoryMethod {
    abstract Car rentCar();

    public void driveCar() {
        Car car = rentCar();
        car.drive();
    }

    public static class AudiFactoryMethod extends FactoryMethod {
        @Override
        Car rentCar() {
            return new Audi("red", 5);
        }
    }

    public static class BmwFactoryMethod extends FactoryMethod {
        @Override
        Car rentCar() {
            return new BMW("black", true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new AudiFactoryMethod().driveCar();
        new BmwFactoryMethod().driveCar();
    }
}
```

As another example, consider a class that depends on a `List`. It could obtain that List through a Factory Method by adding an abstract method `getList()`. This class might then have a `LinkedList` subclass and an `ArrayList` subclass.

---

*** Yes, I know that the GoF describes the use of *parameterized* factory methods; but these are inevitably implemented in violation of the Open-Closed Principle. A static factory method, as described by Josh Bloch, is simpler and more straight-forward in that case.

Comment: Ok but where did you take the Audi c-tor parameters? You hardcoded them, but what if I need to specify them? In your case the BmwFactoryMethod would need to have injected them from somewhere, right?

Comment: The `BmwFactoryMethod` itself would be injected. The purpose of each subclass is to hard-code parameters. To inject different parameters, subclass `FactoryMethod` again.

Comment: You could of course add different constructors to each subclass, and nothing in the Factory Method Pattern restricts you from doing so; but at that point I would consider alternative designs. In my own opinion, this example shows the readable and maintainable way to implement Factory Method. Parameterized implementations are confusing and tend to violate SOLID principles like OCP and LSP.

Comment: The GoF defines two factory patterns: Factory Method and Abstract Factory. In practice, you will never use either one. You are more likely to use the (unofficially named) Simple Factory and/or Josh Bloch's Static Factory. SO questions claiming to implement the GoF patterns will inevitably be incorrect, and will often have implemented one of these less famous (but more common) alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead ?

That way you can have methods allowing you to set each attribute independently, and provide suitable defaults such that you don't need to specify them explicitly if not required.

e.g.

```
BuilderFor.type("Audi").withColor("Red").withTurnAssist().build();
```

so the above effectively uses a factory to give you the appropriate builder

Comment: Because I need to see how would factory method apply to some related classes but with different constructors. ( and of course if it can apply or not )

Comment: Are you saying is this not suitable for factory method at all?

Comment: I think a builder may be more suitable

Comment: But can you suggest please, how would you do it with factory method? Or it cannot be done with that, only with simple factory and builder pattern?

Comment: Factory method alone may not work in case where you want to customized the propertis. You can mix other patterns to get a better design.  For such cases a factory + decorator can be a good choice